# Rails 4 Paperclip with Devise, file saving error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, paperclip

I'm using devise gem with paperclip to handle authentication and upload pictures. Problem is that I have used paperclip on the same model twice for storing two pictures (let's call those paperclip columns :avatar , :superbadge), my model name is User.

Now, when I choose to upload two pictures, my rails application ignores the first file that I have chosen, instead It uses second chosen file and saves it in the **first paperclip column, leaving second paperclip column blank**. How do I fix it?

My application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_devise_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

    def configure_devise_permitted_parameters
        registration_params = [:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,:avatar,:superstarbadge]

        if params[:action] == "update"
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) {
            |u| u.permit(registration_params << :current_password)
          }
        elsif params[:action] == "create"
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {
            |u| u.permit(registration_params)
          }
        end 
    end
end
```

My User.rb model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :validatable
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :small => "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  has_attached_file :superstarbadge, :styles => { :tiny => "100x100>" }, :default => "superbadge.jpg" 
  validates_attachment_content_type :superstarbadge, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers

  def to_s
    email
  end
end
```

My form_for for creating new user with devise gem (I'm using slim template language not erb):

```
h1 Sign up

= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!

  .field
    label= f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name, autofocus: true

  .field
    label= f.label :email
    = f.email_field :email, autofocus: true

  .field
    label= f.label :password
    = f.password_field :password, autocomplete: 'off'

  .field
    label= f.label :password_confirmation
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: 'off'

  .field
    = f.label :avatar
    = f.file_field :avatar

  .field 
    = f.file_field :avatar

  div
    = f.submit "Sign up"
```

Comment: Both of your `file_field`'s are for `:avatar` don't you want one of them to be for `:superbadge`

Comment: I need new glasses, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the *file_field's* in your form are referring to `avatar` field so when you submit the form the second chosen file (i.e., *latest*) gets saved as `avatar`. There is no *file_field* for `superstarbadge` so it never gets saved.

You need one *file_field* for `avatar` and other one for `superstarbadge`. So, your code should look like:

```
.field
  = f.label :avatar
  = f.file_field :avatar

.field 
  = f.file_field :superstarbadge ## This one should be superstarbadge and NOT avatar
```